# Differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives

**I've working on the following problem:**

> Consider a solution $(x_1(t),x_2(t),\ldots,x_N(t))$ of the equation
>
> $$\frac{dx_i}{dt}=-\sum_{j=1}^{N}\nabla W(x_i-x_j), i=1,\ldots,n $$
>
> with $W\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ satisfying $$(\nabla W(x)-\nabla W(y))(x-y)\geq \lambda |x-y|^2, $$ for each $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^d,\lambda>0.$ If we define $$V(t):=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}|x_i(t)-\bar x(t)|^2,$$ where $\bar x(t)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i(t),$ then **prove that there exists a constant $A>0$ such that:**
>
> $V(t)\leq V(0)e^{-At},~~t\geq0.$

I think that I have to use somehow the Grönwall's inequality using the given property of the function $W$, so I've tried to derive $V(t)$ and I've obtained this:

$\displaystyle \frac{dV(t)}{dt}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left[(x_i(t)-\bar x)\left(-\sum_{j=1}^{N}(\nabla W(x_i-x_j))+\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\nabla W(x_j-x_k)\right) \right]$.

I don't know how can I continue from this or if I have chosen a good path to solve the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't you have $i\ne j$ in your equations?

Comment: No, take into account that you can evaluate the function $W$ in the vector $0$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: It seems the LHS of the differential equation is a scalar value, but the RHS seems to be a vector (I take \nabla means the gradient).

Comment: @xxjman18 : Yes, that is correct, if the particle positions $x_i$ are vectors, then so are the gradients, and the product in the monotony property is a scalar product of vector and gradient.

Comment: I would have expanded the title, for instance as "gradient flow for aggregation of particles"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bu}{{\bf u}}\newcommand{\bv}{{\bf v}}\newcommand{\bx}{{\bf x}}\newcommand{\mM}{{\rm M}}$
In the case of scalar $x_i$ the expression for the derivative of $V$ has the structure $\dot V=2\bu^T\mM\bv$ with an anti-symmetric matrix $\mM=-\mM^T$,
$$
\mM_{ik}=-\frac{1}{2N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}\left(\nabla W(x_i-x_j) - \nabla W(x_k-x_j)\right),
$$
$\bv$ the vector of ones and $\bu$ the vector of $u_i=x_i-\bar x$.

Exploiting the anti-symmetry one can abstractly transform
$$
\dot V=\bu^T\mM\bv-\bu^T\mM^T\bv={\rm trace}((\bv\bu^T-\bu\bv^T)\mM)
=(\bu\bv^T-\bv\bu^T)\,{\bf :}\,\mM
$$
where $$(\bu\bv^T-\bv\bu^T)_{ik}=u_iv_k-u_kv_i=u_i-u_k=x_i-x_k$$

By the monotonicity condition
$$
(x_i-x_k)\left(\nabla W(x_i-x_j) - \nabla W(x_k-x_j)\right)\ge λ(x_i-x_k)^2.
$$
and thus for the terms inside the Euclidean/Frobenius matrix scalar product
$$
(\bu\bv^T-\bv\bu^T)_{ik}\mM_{ik}\le-\fracλ2(x_i-x_k)^2
$$

Over the $N^2$ terms of the scalar product this makes
\begin{align}
\frac{dV}{dt}&\le -\frac{λN^2}2\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^Nλ(x_i-x_k)^2\\
&=-\frac{λN^2}2\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^N(u_i-u_k)^2\\
&=-\frac{λN^2}2\left[4NV-2\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^Nu_iu_k\right]\\
&=-2λN^3·V
\end{align}
as $\sum_{i=1}^Nu_i=0$.

---

$\newcommand{\dotp}{\vcenter{\huge\cdot}}$
In the vector case for $\bx_i$, $\bu_i=\bx_i-\bar\bx$, the gradients in $M_{ik}$ are also vectors, still with $M_{ik}=-M_{ki}$. Then use the anti-symmetry directly without naming tensors of third order,
$$
2\sum_{i,k}\bu_i\dotp M_{ik}=\sum_{i,k}[\bu_i\dotp M_{ik}-\bu_i\dotp M_{ki}]
=\sum_{i,k}(\bu_i-\bu_k)\dotp M_{ik}
$$
the last step by switching the index labels in the second term. Then proceed as above.

Comment: 1)What is the operator ":" that you've written developing the equation of $\dot{V}$? On the other hand, I have just fixed my expression of $\dot{V}$.

Comment: It is one of several notations for the Frobenius scalar product. $A:B=\langle A,B\rangle_F={\rm trace}(A^TB)$. As said, it it similar to the Euclidean scalar product in that the entries of the same position get multiplied, and then the products get summed up. One could think of the double dot as twice the dot product, once over the rows and once over the columns.